# I need to handle a system generated pop up. Is there any way to get the text within that pop up

Tags: android

I need to handle a system generated pop up. Is there any way to get the text within that pop up. That popup message is not created by my program. Is there any possibility that can we need to handle that popup message. If we can handle it please let me know.

for example :- system generated a pop up message. after making a call we get pop up message stating your balance and stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean Alert Dialog???

Comment: Not exactly alert dialog. its same as alert dialog box. but i don't have the scope of it.

Answer (score 1):

No absolutely you can't, you don't even own this pop up/dialog.

but if you are interested in achieving the same functionality you can do so, such as checking the credit balance using USSD service.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
is there any possibility that we cant get the popup created event.

I am using the my application to check my credit balance using callintent. That gives us the popup message. i should able to read that popup message. can that be possible.

Comment: you can check your balance using the CallIntent by sending USSD code but the Phone App is the one which produce these dialog "to print the result of your USSD code"

Comment: so again no you can't read that text, but you can run USSD codes easily with other methods, remember if that is possible in android, there will be a lot of security breaches.

Comment: @Shashank Reddy; no problem, if you think my answer have leaded some where you think it was helpful, please mark it as an answer.